# Can you alter the content of $OUTPUT->main_content() in moodle?

Tags: php, templates, moodle

I'm aware of similar questions related to this. My task is much more complex than anything css can handle.

in one of the course templates, for example, the whole content area of the page seems to be handled by 3 lines of code...

```
        echo $OUTPUT->course_content_header();
        echo $OUTPUT->main_content();
        echo $OUTPUT->course_content_footer();
```

Suppose you need to add some major changes to the inner content of a course. Something that requires restructuring the markup, data, etc that is clearly handled by `$OUTPUT->main_content()`

Other answers trace it back to libs/outputrenderers.php but if you look into that you find this:

```
public function main_content() {
    // This is here because it is the only place we can inject the "main" role over the entire main content area
    // without requiring all theme's to manually do it, and without creating yet another thing people need to
    // remember in the theme.
    // This is an unfortunate hack. DO NO EVER add anything more here.
    // DO NOT add classes.
    // DO NOT add an id.

    return '<div role="main">'.$this->unique_main_content_token.'</div>';
}
```

... trace back `$this->unique_main_content_token` and you get nothing as well.

Somewhere, in all this mess, there MUST be something that's assembling all the data and markup. I don't just need to override the main_content() function in my child theme. All that will give me is a blank slate. I need to know how it's pulling the data to generate the page so I can access things like course titles, user status, etc. And additionally inject my own modifications where they belong as opposed to trying to meddle with css absolute positioning or post load js manipulation. I'll get dirty if I have to, but I'd rather understand the system before I have to chop it to bits.

Does anyone know where to find exactly where the html of `$OUTPUT->main_content()` is handled, in general or for courses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moodle works with what they call "renderers". The method `main_content` is the way themers indicate where the main content is to be rendered in the their theme.

The way Moodle renders pages is by letting the developer echo anything they want after the first call to `$OUTPUT->header()`, they then have to end the output with `$OUTPUT->footer()`. Under the hood, the layout file provided by the themer is split in two, one part echoed by `$OUTPUT->header()`, and the rest by `$OUTOUT->footer()`.

So unfortunately you won't be able to catch all of the content, except perhaps if you override the methods mentioned above and introduce your own output buffering. Though, by convention output should be generated by renderers which you can override in your theme. Regardless of the solution you're heading for, a theme is probably a good start.

Also depending on what you are trying to achieve, for instance changing the layout of the course, you may be better of looking at other plugin types, such as "Course formats".

I hope this helped.

- [Moodle renderers](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Output_renderers)
- [Moodle course formats](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Course_formats)

To clarify, to override a renderer you MUST create a new theme, and then create a renderer class. If you want to override more than `core` renderers, say renderers of plugins like `mod_scorm`, you must create a renderer class of a specific name.

Examples:

```
class theme_yourtheme_core_renderer extends core_renderer { 
    // Overridden core renderer methods here.
}
class theme_yourtheme_mod_scorm_renderer extends mod_scorm_renderer {
    // Overridden scorm renderer methods here.
}
```

I suggest that you read the documentation below, however confusing it may be. I also recommend that you skim through the code of other themes which have been pretty creative with their uses of renderers.

- [How to override renderers](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Overriding_a_renderer)
- [Essential's theme mod_assign renderer](https://github.com/gjb2048/moodle-theme_essential/blob/master/classes/mod_assign_renderer.php)

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to find a way to back trace the renderers responsible for the output to a page, similar to a feature in drupal which will outline various components and identify the view responsible for those blocks. So far I've found nothing per say and manually tracking the renderers down is a nightmare. Example - good luck overriding the renderer for a scorm. Completely undocumented as far as I can tell.

Comment: Indeed, there is some digging to do. Regarding SCORM, they should all be in the plugin's renderer class. `mod_scorm_renderer` in `mod/scorm/renderer.php`.

Comment: The scorm renderers are there. I just don't know how to override them. When I try to apply the same render override provided in moodle examples it just kills the page with a white screen. I wasn't sure if it just doesn't like overriding from /mod or if i'm doing things incorrectly. error handling in this seems pretty bad

Comment: I feel your pain. I've added a bit to my answer, hopefully it helps.

Comment: Yeah that's pretty much what I've been doing. Downloading themes and reverse engineering them. I haven't found any yet that address all of my issues though. Thanks for the samples. I bet this will help someone down the line somewhere

Comment: No problem. If you need more help, shoot me an e-mail at fred at branchup dot tech.